# is there a numeric type in SQL with a maximum length?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL and I need an attribute type that can store a numeric value that can't have more than 7 digits.

Is there an attribute like that or do I need to make it a text column that can only store numbers?

Answer (score 4):

`DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` (synonyms for each other) will provide this functionality.  You specify total digits, and digits to the right of the decimal point.  For example `NUMERIC(9,7)` for ##.#######.

Comment: Alternatively use an `integer` with a check constraint if no fractional digits are required.

Answer (score 1):

Often, when you have a "numeric" value that is fixed in digits, then you really have something like an account number.  Although this looks like a number, it really, it really isn't for a few reasons:

- Leading zeros are important
- You can't perform arithmetic on the value
- Sometimes, individual digits might have a particular meaning

If this is what you are trying to do, I would suggest that you use `CHAR(7)` and explicitly include leading zeroes.  If you really do have a number with these constraints, you can use `DECIMAL(7)`.  If you do use `CHAR(7)`, you can use a check constraint to validate the digits.

Comment: I was with you until you suggested `CHAR`. Ugh. I'd use a `CHECK` constraint on a `varchar` or `text` field and be done with it. The padding rules in `char` are ghastly.

Comment: @CraigRinger . . . I'm assuming there is no padding and all the codes are seven characters, such as zip codes in the United States.